# Naming conventions for instance, local and parameter variables

Tags: java, naming, variables

I was discussing with a senior developper coding conventions to apply to our projects (mainly Java/JEE projects). I disagreed with one convention he proposed:

> Instance variable names should start with "_", local variables with
>   "loc", and method parameters with "par", so it would be easy to identify
>   a variable origin and scope.

While he put forward arguments for short-term memory and readability, I disagreed on the fact that it rather decreases readability, IDEs like Eclipse format variables differently depending on their type, and this problem would be avoided with a good class and method design.

Do you have any opinion, arguments or studies that supports my point (or opposes it)?

Comment: You say that you disagreed on "the fact that it rather decreases readability." I'm not saying you're wrong, but what evidence did you provide to support that claim? I'm not aware of any research that says it will decrease readability (I studied cognitive at graduate school psychology before becoming a developer, so this is an area of interest for me.)

Comment: I meant it as it is cluttering. But I don't have any evidence other than my personal opinion

Comment: The prefixes duplicate information that is already contained in the code and displayed in any half-decent environment. And as we all know, duplicate information can become inconsistent. DRY should point you towards not using the prefixes.

Comment: @JuliaHayward Will github do such highlighting? I don't think that's the case (from experience). It's not just the IDE. It's all the tooling used along the way.

Answer (score 14):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29) says on the subject - Rules for naming of java,

> Local variables, instance variables, and class variables are also
>   written in lowerCamelCase. Variable names should not start with
>   underscore (_) or dollar sign ($) characters, even though both are
>   allowed. Certain coding conventions state that underscores should be
>   used to prefix all instance variables, for improved reading and
>   program understanding.

According to my experience with coding standards, Instance variable names start with "_" is not much good as wikipedia standards say.

local variables with "loc", and method parameters with "par", as you said it would be easy to identify a variable origin and scope, but it should be for you, not the other programmers who may go through your code for maintenance someday.

As per the [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) specification about the methods these should be short as much they can you do for readability and variables names should should not be mind mapped, they should be relevant to your operation that your method perform.

Member/Scope Prefixes, 
You also don’t need to prefix member variables with m_ anymore. Your classes and functions
should be small enough that you don’t need them. And you should be using an editing
environment that highlights or colorizes members to make them distinct.

```
public class Part {
private String m_dsc; // The textual description
void setName(String name) {
m_dsc = name;
}
}
```

---

```
public class Part {
String description;
void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}
}
```

Besides, people quickly learn to ignore the prefix (or suffix) to see the meaningful
part of the name. The more we read the code, the less we see the prefixes. Eventually the
prefixes become unseen clutter and a marker of older code.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I'm going to post here anyway. I have some 20+ years of programming and dealing with other people's code.

I think that naming your variable with a short indication as to their scope is really really useful for the next person (or yourself) who will look at your code.

One does not already look at code in an IDE with pretty colors (and I can't remember what the colors means and different IDE show different colors, etc).

True, methods should be short enough so it's not loaded with tons of variables and tons of code but even on short one - when you look at code that is totally unfamiliar, it is sometimes hard to tell whether a variable is a class variable, local variable or method parameter.

To be able to distinguish at a glance makes it very easy to review the code you are unfamiliar with.

Take this example:

```
public <T> Page<T> moreLikeThis(MoreLikeThisQuery query, Class<T> clazz) {
    int startRecord = 0;
    ElasticsearchPersistentEntity persistentEntity = getPersistentEntityFor(clazz);
    String indexName = isNotBlank(query.getIndexName()) ? query.getIndexName() : persistentEntity.getIndexName();
    String type = isNotBlank(query.getType()) ? query.getType() : persistentEntity.getIndexType();

    Assert.notNull(indexName, "No 'indexName' defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");
    Assert.notNull(type, "No 'type' defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");
    Assert.notNull(query.getId(), "No document id defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");

    MoreLikeThisRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareMoreLikeThis(indexName, type, query.getId());

    if (query.getPageable() != null) {
        startRecord = query.getPageable().getPageNumber() * query.getPageable().getPageSize();
        requestBuilder.setSearchSize(query.getPageable().getPageSize());
    }
    requestBuilder.setSearchFrom(startRecord);

    if (isNotEmpty(query.getSearchIndices())) {
        requestBuilder.setSearchIndices(toArray(query.getSearchIndices()));
    }
    if (isNotEmpty(query.getSearchTypes())) {
        requestBuilder.setSearchTypes(toArray(query.getSearchTypes()));
    }
    if (isNotEmpty(query.getFields())) {
        requestBuilder.setField(toArray(query.getFields()));
    }
    if (isNotBlank(query.getRouting())) {
        requestBuilder.setRouting(query.getRouting());
    }
    if (query.getPercentTermsToMatch() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setPercentTermsToMatch(query.getPercentTermsToMatch());
    }
    if (query.getMinTermFreq() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setMinTermFreq(query.getMinTermFreq());
    }
    if (query.getMaxQueryTerms() != null) {
        requestBuilder.maxQueryTerms(query.getMaxQueryTerms());
    }
    if (isNotEmpty(query.getStopWords())) {
        requestBuilder.setStopWords(toArray(query.getStopWords()));
    }
    if (query.getMinDocFreq() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setMinDocFreq(query.getMinDocFreq());
    }
    if (query.getMaxDocFreq() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setMaxDocFreq(query.getMaxDocFreq());
    }
    if (query.getMinWordLen() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setMinWordLen(query.getMinWordLen());
    }
    if (query.getMaxWordLen() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setMaxWordLen(query.getMaxWordLen());
    }
    if (query.getBoostTerms() != null) {
        requestBuilder.setBoostTerms(query.getBoostTerms());
    }

    SearchResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
    return resultsMapper.mapResults(response, clazz, query.getPageable());
}
```

Now, time yourself and look at the code (extracted from ElasticsearchTemplate from the spring-data-elasticsearch project - the code I was reviewing which prompted me to search on Google for what people say about naming conventions).

- What's the scode of `resultsMapper`?
- Is `requestBuilding` a parameter?
- etc...

Here is my simple suggestion on how variables should be named:

- Class static attributes (i.e. constants): ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES (e.g. `HOST_NAME`).
- Class attributes (i.e. class instance variables): camelCase (e.g. `resultsMapper`).
- Method parameters: prefixed with `a` (e.g. `aQuery`, `aClazz`).
- Local variables: prefixed with `my` (e.g. `myIndexName`, `myType`).

The code above becomes:

```
public <T> Page<T> moreLikeThis(MoreLikeThisQuery aQuery, Class<T> aClazz) {
  int myStartRecord = 0;
  ElasticsearchPersistentEntity myPersistentEntity = getPersistentEntityFor(aClazz);
  String myIndexName = isNotBlank(aQuery.getIndexName()) ? aQuery.getIndexName() : myPersistentEntity.getIndexName();
  String myType = isNotBlank(aQuery.getType()) ? aQuery.getType() : myPersistentEntity.getIndexType();

  Assert.notNull(myIndexName, "No 'indexName' defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");
  Assert.notNull(myType, "No 'type' defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");
  Assert.notNull(aQuery.getId(), "No document id defined for MoreLikeThisQuery");

  MoreLikeThisRequestBuilder myRequestBuilder = client.prepareMoreLikeThis(myIndexName, myType, aQuery.getId());

  if (aQuery.getPageable() != null) {
     myStartRecord = aQuery.getPageable().getPageNumber() * aQuery.getPageable().getPageSize();
     myRequestBuilder.setSearchSize(aQuery.getPageable().getPageSize());
  }
  myRequestBuilder.setSearchFrom(myStartRecord);

  if (isNotEmpty(aQuery.getSearchIndices())) {
     myRequestBuilder.setSearchIndices(toArray(aQuery.getSearchIndices()));
  }
  if (isNotEmpty(aQuery.getSearchTypes())) {
     myRequestBuilder.setSearchTypes(toArray(aQuery.getSearchTypes()));
  }
  if (isNotEmpty(aQuery.getFields())) {
     myRequestBuilder.setField(toArray(aQuery.getFields()));
  }
  if (isNotBlank(aQuery.getRouting())) {
     myRequestBuilder.setRouting(aQuery.getRouting());
  }
  if (aQuery.getPercentTermsToMatch() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setPercentTermsToMatch(aQuery.getPercentTermsToMatch());
  }
  if (aQuery.getMinTermFreq() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setMinTermFreq(aQuery.getMinTermFreq());
  }
  if (aQuery.getMaxQueryTerms() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.maxQueryTerms(aQuery.getMaxQueryTerms());
  }
  if (isNotEmpty(aQuery.getStopWords())) {
     myRequestBuilder.setStopWords(toArray(aQuery.getStopWords()));
  }
  if (aQuery.getMinDocFreq() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setMinDocFreq(aQuery.getMinDocFreq());
  }
  if (aQuery.getMaxDocFreq() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setMaxDocFreq(aQuery.getMaxDocFreq());
  }
  if (aQuery.getMinWordLen() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setMinWordLen(aQuery.getMinWordLen());
  }
  if (aQuery.getMaxWordLen() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setMaxWordLen(aQuery.getMaxWordLen());
  }
  if (aQuery.getBoostTerms() != null) {
     myRequestBuilder.setBoostTerms(aQuery.getBoostTerms());
  }

  SearchResponse myResponse = myRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
  return resultsMapper.mapResults(myResponse, aClazz, aQuery.getPageable());
```

}

Is that perfect? I don't think so. But the above, as far as variables are concerned, is now easier to read. There are other things such as alignment and spacing, which I won't get into in this answer as it is not related to the question, which would make it easier to read as well.

You don't like Camel Case? Fine, use underscores, etc, but prefix your local variables and your parameters to make them different than class instance variables.

You don't like `a` and `my` - fine, just stay consistent within your project and use something else... but do use something.

**Rule #1:** consistency within the project.

**Rule #2:** make it easy to read and don't require the reader to know everything before he can learn.

Comment: I am a proponent of having leading `_` for class variables. `a` and `my` are worst. What if the variable name itself starts with a vowel, do you still prefix with `a`, or does it become `an` now? Code should be _readable_, and I refuse to read variable names like `aEgg`.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - call it `anEgg`.

Comment: I sure can do that, but then it looks like I'm doing English rather than coding. And all this seems very useless and superfluous when we can achieve the same thing with just a single, innocent character prefix, a leading `_`.

Comment: Using `_` for class attributes/variables sure - but then how do you distinguish between a local variable and a parameter? It does not really matter what you do. My proposition is that there should be something that distinguish them other than the beautiful colors of your IDE because, you don't always look at code in a pretty color IDE and some people are color blind...

Answer (score 3):

This is largely a matter of preference, and as such there is no 'correct' answer. So, this question might actually be closed. But before it does, let me tell you that I totally agree with you. Prefixes decrease visibility as far as I am concerned. Let alone the fact that if there are to be any prefixes, they should be used for more useful stuff, like [the original intention of the Hungarian Notation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/102690/41811), and not for things that your IDE can provide highlighting for anyway.

I use SentenceCase for instance data (whether variables or constants) and lower_case for parameters and local variables, since there really is very little, if any, difference between the two. I never, ever use headlessCamelCase because **it is lame**: a single-component identifier looks like lowercase, even if it was intended to be headlessCamelCase.